With native bash in Linux, how to output K as in Kubuntu?
Using:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'


Question clarified 1:
How does neofetch do it?
What command is neofetch using to output K?
as in:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64  


Question clarified 2:
Using Linux terminal, what is the command
to output K as in Kubuntu
with native bash and
Not doing a manual addition of K
Not using an additional program to install
Not using neofetch as in
Not using
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'

giving
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64  


Question clarified 3:
undesired output because no K with  :
lsb_release -sd && lsb_release -sr && lsb_release -si

Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS  
22.04  
Ubuntu  


Question clarified 4:
The undesired output with
AI (Artificial Intelligence) at
https://www.ecosia.org/chat?q=ai does a manual addition of K with:
lsb_release -sd | sed 's/Ubuntu/Kubuntu/' && echo " $(uname -m)"

Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS  
 x86_64  


Question clarified 5:
What is a web page address for an AI (Artificial Intelligence) better tuned to bash commands?
using:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'

Neofetch 7.1.0
neofetch --version

GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release
bash --version |sed -n '1p' |awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4}'


Where does the assumption that Neofetch has to rely on another command (to output the name) come from?

What is under the hood?
What is beneath the surface?
How is Neofetch showing desired output?
What is neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'   calling?  and
What is the equal in bash that gives desired output?

Define "in bash". What makes a given command "in bash" as opposed to one that isn't? If you run neofetch --stdout from bash, does that count as "in bash" or not?


Define "in bash". _ Native bash.
No additional programs to install.
No manual addition of K.
See details in Question under Question clarified 2:



What command is neofetch using to output K ?

None. It generates this output by itself.
Realize that Neofetch is in itself a program, or a 'command' as you call it. It doesn't need to rely on additional tools to generate output – it can just directly write any text it wants to its stdout.

What is under the hood? What is beneath the surface?

The source code of Neofetch is available publicly: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch
Specifically, look for the block "Get Ubuntu flavor" at: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/master/neofetch#L1127-L1139 – where, if Ubuntu is detected as the distribution, Neofetch checks the currently active desktop environment (in an oddly indirect way, via $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS, but perhaps this happens to better reflect what's installed?) and if it detects KDE Plasma, it replaces the string Ubuntu with Kubuntu.
That is, it really does a manual addition of K.
get_distro() {
    [...]

    distro=$(trim_quotes "$distro")
    distro=${distro/NAME=}

    # Get Ubuntu flavor.
    if [[ $distro == "Ubuntu"* ]]; then
        case $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS in
            *"studio"*)   distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Ubuntu Studio} ;;
            *"plasma"*)   distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Kubuntu} ;;
            *"mate"*)     distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Ubuntu MATE} ;;
            *"xubuntu"*)  distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Xubuntu} ;;
            *"Lubuntu"*)  distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Lubuntu} ;;
            *"budgie"*)   distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Ubuntu Budgie} ;;
            *"cinnamon"*) distro=${distro/Ubuntu/Ubuntu Cinnamon} ;;
        esac
    fi

    [...]
}


Native bash.   No additional programs to install.  No manual addition of K

There's no such command. In the strict sense of "native Bash" – Bash has no built-in commands that would report the distribution, so it would necessarily have to be either an external command or reading from some plain-text file.
Generally speaking, the closest thing to a "pure Bash" solution would be the /etc/os-release file, which has a NAME= variable that identifies the distribution (in a bash-compatible syntax). However, the issue is that Kubuntu is not a separate distribution – it still uses the same packages as Ubuntu, and therefore the same /etc/os-release file, so it will always identify itself as "Ubuntu".
In the loose sense, as in "only commands that come with the OS" – same answer; as far as I know Kubuntu doesn't install any such commands.
